# Entity Framework save changes to context causing error

Tags: c#, collections, entity-framework-5

I am trying to save changes to my context which has two items. One is new, the other is old. I am able to get the list of objects back and save a single item with no issues, however the moment I have two items and call save it bombs out saying:

**Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.**

Snippet of my code below.

Thank you.

```
    protected bool Save(params T[] entities)
    {
        foreach (T entity in entities)
        {
            bool b = context.Entry<T>(entity).Member<int>(string.Format("{0}Id", typeof(T).Name)).CurrentValue > 0;

            if (b)
            {
                context.Context.Attach(entity);
                context.Entry<T>(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
            }
            else
            {
                context.Context.Add(entity);
                context.Entry<T>(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
            }
        }
        return context.SaveChanges() > 0;
    }
```

Comment: When you attach entity like that, are you sure that corresponding row with the same key exists in database table? The error is saying that you are trying to update record that does not exist in db. Or you have ConcurencyCheck|Timestamp attribute and the row you are updateing has different values in database.

Comment: If I understand correctly, first you check if the item is already in a database, if it is, you attach, if it is not, you add. But when you attach, was it detached before? Don't you have two entities with the same id after you attach?

Comment: I have two items in a list. One is newly added (does not exist in database) and the other is loaded from database. When updating it is fine, the one being added is throwing this exception and don't know why..

Comment: Bah lightbulb moment! I am such noob! Made key on table primary key and auto generated column and bang it works. I am such a noob :'( thanks for the help guys, reading your comments triggered the lightbulb!

Answer (score 0):

Needed a primary key on table which is also auto generated.